# How to create a new img tag with JQuery, with the src and id from a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I understand JQuery in the basic sense but am definitely new to it, and suspect this is very easy.

I've got my image src and id in a JSON response (converted to an object), and therefore the correct values in responseObject.imgurl and responseObject.imgid, and now I'd like to create an image with it and  append it to a div (lets call it `<div id="imagediv">`.  I'm a bit stuck on dynamically building the `<img src="dynamic" id="dynamic">` - most of the examples I've seen involve replacing the src on an existing image, but I don't have an existing image.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

In jQuery, a new element can be created by passing a HTML string to the constructor, as shown below:

```
var img = $('<img id="dynamic">'); //Equivalent: $(document.createElement('img'))
img.attr('src', responseObject.imgurl);
img.appendTo('#imagediv');
```

Comment: @a7omiton View source via contextmenu or via the inspector? The contextmenu (or Ctrl + U) shows the data received from the server without the changes made by JavaScript. Use the DOM inspector to see the document's active HTML with live changes.

Comment: Oops sorry I deleted the comment :/, it does show up in the dev tools now, the page was hanging because of the jquery map 404 issue

Comment: You are right however that the images don't show up on the source page (ctrl + u)

Comment: @a7omiton You can disable the 404 warnings about jquery.min.map by clicking on the gears icon in the bottom-right corner and disabling the "Enable source maps" option.

Comment: Yes, I was just looking at the solution by paul_irish (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365315/jquerys-jquery-1-10-2-min-map-is-triggering-a-404-not-found). Thanks for that :)

Comment: Remember - if the `attr` is `undefined` then the attribute is not going to show up in the created element

Answer (score 93):

```
var img = $('<img />', { 
  id: 'Myid',
  src: 'MySrc.gif',
  alt: 'MyAlt'
});
img.appendTo($('#YourDiv'));
```

Answer (score 19):

You save some bytes by avoiding the `.attr` altogether by passing the properties to the [jQuery constructor](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes):

```
var img = $('<img />',
             { id: 'Myid',
               src: 'MySrc.gif', 
               width: 300
             })
              .appendTo($('#YourDiv'));
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who need the same feature in IE 8, this is how I solved the problem:

```
  var myImage = $('<img/>');

               myImage.attr('width', 300);
               myImage.attr('height', 300);
               myImage.attr('class', "groupMediaPhoto");
               myImage.attr('src', photoUrl);
```

I could not force IE8 to use object in constructor.