# An Image inside a dynamically created div tags

Tags: c#, javascript

What is required is to dynamically create six div tags using Javascript, that will resize with the width of the window( either computer, iphone, ipad, Blackberry etc). that task has been successfully achieved. The next task is to place an image in each of the created div tag, **Remember the divs are created dynamically and the image has to be clickable.** I have a folder containing the images.

**Please help am new at this**.

**Note:The Images should resize as the divs resizes*
Here is the code for the dynamically created div tags. Please In details illustrate how best can i achieve this.

```
function DynamicDiv()
{
    for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        var dynDiv = document.createElement("div");
        dynDiv.className = "blocks";
        document.body.appendChild(dynDiv);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you tag this with jQuery?

Comment: have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013792/how-to-create-a-new-img-tag-with-jquery-with-the-src-and-id-from-a-javascript-o

Answer (score 0):

what you can try with is create html as string and append the same to the element.

```
var html='<div>';
html='<img src="'+ImagePathforDynamic+'" alt="'+ImageAlterText+'"'/>;
html+='</div>';
$('#idOfElement').append(html);
```

oh! need to add events

```
$('#idOfElement img').click(function(){
    // your code to perform on click of the image
});
```

or if you want to have multiple divs then you can have loop that can generate html for the same.
Let me know if this does not help you ;)