# jquery - Undefined src when using attr() of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just learning jQuery. What I want is to grab the src of the image and display it in a fixed division, kind of like a pop up, with the title of the image. But I'm stuck at getting the src of the image.

When I tried using the .attr(), its giving me `undefined`.

HTML:

```
            <div id="album">

                <div class="pic">

                </div>

                <div class="screen">
                    <h1 class="title">Photo 1</h1>
                    <img src="images/1 png.png" class="image" />
                    <p class="description">This is a description</p>
                </div>

                <div class="screen">
                    <h1 class="title">Photo 1</h1>
                    <img src="images/1 png.png" class="image" />
                    <p class="description">This is a description</p>
                </div>
                <span class="clear_left"></span>

            </div>
```

css:

```
.screen {
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin: 10px auto;
    float: left;
    cursor:pointer
}

.image {
    width: 300px;

}

.title {
    font-size: 30px;
}

.description {
    font-size: 25px;
}

.pic {
    width: 600px;
    position:fixed;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".pic").hide();
    $(".screen").click(function () {
        display();
    });
});

function display() {
    var source = $("img",this).attr("src");
    alert("The souce of the image is " + source);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, the `display()` method does not have the context of the element being clicked. Hence it is showing `undefined`

So, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".pic").hide();
    $(".screen").click(function () {
        display($(this));
    });
});

function display($this) {
    var source = $("img", $this).attr("src");
    alert("The souce of the image is " + source);
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xTkwL/)

Comment: Thanks it worked! How do I pass this src and display it in the div (.pic)? I have added `$('.pic').show();`, but I don't know how to pass the src to display the image and its description in the .pic div.

Comment: That is simple: This post should help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013792/how-to-create-a-new-img-tag-with-jquery-with-the-src-and-id-from-a-javascript-o

Answer (score 1):

Dont wrap your function call with another anonymous function:

Demo:    http://jsfiddle.net/9KgSQ/

```
$(".screen").click(display);
```

This will now pass along `this` to your function.

Answer (score 0):

`this` in the `display` function is referring to your anonymous function, not the element.  You don't need to wrap it.  `$('.screen').click(display)` will make sure that `this` references the `.screen` element.

I would also change display to do this instead:

```
function display() {
    var source = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    alert("The source of the image is " + source);
}
```

This wraps jQuery around the `.screen` element that was clicked on and finds the `img` element inside of it.  I think it's a little more clear, but this is just a preference thing.

Comment: That is the same as `"img", this`

Answer (score 0):

It's because the value of `this` in `display` is not the same as the value of `this` in the click function for `.screen`. You can do a test for that by calling `console.log(this);` within the `display` function to see what the value of `this` is.

If you want to pass the value of `this` on to `display` you can use the [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) function like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".pic").hide();
    $(".screen").click(function () {
        display.call(this);
    });
});

function display() {
    var source = $("img", this).attr("src");
    alert("The souce of the image is " + source);
}
```

Or you could completely get rid of the anonymous function and pass in `display` directly:

```
$(".screen").click(display);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your src IS undefined.

```
function display() {
    var source = $("img",this).attr("src", "images/okay.jpg");
    alert("The souce of the image is " + source);
}
```