# Pulling images from an html page in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was given a task to pull images from an html page using only jQuery and nothing else.

The html page is a page with a lot of tables and a lot of different png's. In about 400 lines of html, there are about 80 images. My job is to get all of the images with a certain domain to the bottom of the page (the `div class="code">` section), so I can then manually go through them to save them.

So far I am able to get the src of all of the images, but I am not sure how to get all of the actual images. I was thinking if I was to save the source in a variable, I could just redirect the each loop to an `img` tag and feed it the image source. So far it just returns a broken img link, so I think I have the right idea, but not the right code.

Here is my js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("img[src*='tieks']").each(function() {  // src* so I only get certain images
               imgsrc = this.src;
               $(".code").append(imgsrc);
            }); 
   });
```

This is the code section

```
<div class="code">
    <img src=imgsrc>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how I could tackle this?

Comment: Not clear. Your HTML has just a single image.  Where are pulling them from and where do you need to place them?

Comment: what does `pull images from page` even mean?

Comment: when you say save them, can log a list to the browser console if that helps. Not sure what `save` means. Or you can loop through them and make an ajax request to server for each one. In the past I've even created sql `insert` statements in the console. Then copied those statements right into a database tool and have them inserted in a db in next to no time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to clone all the images into one container:

```
$('.code').append( $("img[src*='tieks']").clone() );
```

**[clone() API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)**

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to create a new element and append it to your div or whatever you prefer.

```
var img = $('<img id="dynamic">'); //Equivalent: $(document.createElement('img'))
img.attr('src', responseObject.imgurl);
img.appendTo('#imagediv');
```

This is also answered in this thread from where the example above origins: [How to create a new img tag with JQuery, with the src and id from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013792/how-to-create-a-new-img-tag-with-jquery-with-the-src-and-id-from-a-javascript-o)

Comment: Probably better to change the id for each image instead of using `dynamic` for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying coding is correct.you are taken only image source.If u want to take all the original images and append to div with class 'code',you will try to change

$("img[src*='tieks']").each(function() {

```
    $(".code").append(this);
```

});

just try it.