# Problems with using img src through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple problem. I am getting this carInfo data from a JSON file but can't get the img source to properly part the variable $imgsrc instead of parsing it as a string called "$imgsrc". Then I am appending this to my HTML code.

```
var $imgsrc = "images/vehicles/" + carInfo[i].smallImage;
var $container = .... + '<img src = '$imgsrc'>' + ....;

$('body').append($container);
```

EDIT:

```
+ ... '<img src = "images/vehicles/ + '$imgsrc'">' + ...
```

This gives me a error due to the opening single quote of $imgsrc is actually closing the single quote in the beginning of the  tag

Comment: What does "part the variable $imgsrc " mean in your question?

Comment: If you want `'<img src = "images/vehicles/ + '$imgsrc'">'` to be interpreted as something meaningful, you should probably write something like `'<img src = "images/vehicles/' + $imgsrc + '">'`.

Comment: your question is related with the following link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013792/how-to-create-a-new-img-tag-with-jquery-with-the-src-and-id-from-a-javascript-o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

shouldnt you just do this:

```
var $container = .... + '<img src = '+ $imgsrc +'>' + ....;
```

Comment: Oh wow can't believe I just forgot the + sign. New with JS but thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the var to the string

```
var $container = .... + '<img src="' + $imgsrc + '">' + ....;
```

Comment: strange answer, its clear that is not php, as he decleard it with `var $imgsrc`